# Burial depth of corrugated pipe

Tags: gutters

Water from the gutter downspout is to be directed into [4" corrugated black polypropylene pipe](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FLEX-Drain-4-in-x-25-ft-Solid-Polypropylene-Pipe-52110D/202745403).  To what depth should the pipe be buried?  Assume a Florida venue: so freezing is not a concern.   [Example, albeit MN.](https://www.instructables.com/id/Bury-your-Gutter-Downspouts/)

If it is not buried deep enough, it could be damaged by a lawnmower or somebody stepping on it.  Burying it deeper than necessary is unnecessary digging.

Solid Corrugated Pipe (no holes) Update:

[image]

A single piece of solid (vs perferated) 25-foot length was installed to minimize the possibility of joint failures

Comment: I think it's more up to the laws of gravity... water flows downhill and the pipe system design must allow for that.

Answer (score 2):

Based only on personal experience, not any sort of reference, 6" cover (so a 10 inch trench depth for a 4 inch pipe) is a reasonable minimum unless your lawnmower is one of those things that weighs as much as a small car.

Comment: Thank you: this is helpful guidance

Comment: Based on other personal experience - if you can use straight sections of rigid drainage pipe and fittings, it's much easier to get/keep correct slope than fighting with corrugated. And since the holes can be correctly placed on the bottom rather than being punched all around the pipe, it's less likely to fill up with dirt.